# Fit random images into one composition image using a script

Tags: python, imagick

I am trying to write a script (in bash using imagemagick or in python), to generate an image similar as in this example:

[image: example of composition]

The source is 25 separate jpeg's. So far I have written a script (imagemagick) which takes each of the images and detects the contours of the person and replaces the white background with a transparent one.

The next step is to fit the contours randomly into one large image. Each image should fit into the larger image, without overlapping it's neighbors. It seems I need to some type of collision detection.

I am looking for pointers on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Is there some sort of pattern/orientation/etc. in which the individual pictures have to be assembled or are they pasted randomly? One simple way is to create a mask, choose a random position and paste the image if the masks does not overlap an existing mask. If the images have to follow a pattern or are altered in size and orientation to fit in, then there are many many approaches.  You have to be a bit more specific maybe.

Comment: Yes, using a mask could be an option. Fill in the first image top-left, update the mask and place the next image top-left in the mask and so forth. There is no difference in size, but the number of images is flexible.

Comment: But what happens if you want 100 images in it and thats not possible without fitting the images?

Comment: Yes, that's something to think about too. In that case it will be needed to resize the individual images but it will be hard to predict what size they need to have. I guess I could estimate the individual size, try to fit in all images. If that fails, reduce the size and try again.

Comment: Well, yes thats one way. There are other more "optimal" solution. But don't you have a more specific question? Recommendations are not very popular here.

Comment: Yes, I agree my question is far from specific. I will try to reformulate the question. Could you say something about more optimal solutions?

Comment: Randomly putting stuff in there or random fitting is not robust nor very elegant. If your goals is e.g. putting as many images in without overlapping, there are already some algorithms.

Comment: One issue that makes this hard is that you want to put opaque parts of some images into transparent areas of other images to compact them. This means that one has to test the opaque parts of each new image with all the space left that corresponds to transparent or unused areas. This becomes hard since you are not testing a full rectangle vs the remaining space.